# What’s the difference?

Tags: grammar

What’s the difference?

1. You can’t call me with that name.
2. You can’t be calling me with that name.

Comment: What do you think? Haven'y you done any research?

Comment: I did it, but I’m confused. That’s why I approached here

Comment: If you did, you need to include your research.

Comment: I will do that. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

In the fist case, the speaker is *denying permission* to the audience. Saying "You can't call me with that name" is equivalent to "I will not allow you to use that name to refer to me." An example may help:

> **Clarence**: I hate the nickname Clare. You can't call me with that name!

In the second case, the speaker is either *expressing sarcastic disbelief* or *reprimanding* the audience. Either way, somebody has already called the speaker by the name they dislike, and the speaker is expressing their displeasure at it.

> **Clarence:** Please do not use the name "Clare" to refer to me.
>
> **Bob**: Hey Clare, you wanna go get lunch!
>
> **Clarence**: You can't be calling me by that name! I just asked you not to!

The second version of the phrase is also slightly influenced by dialect. In some English-speaking places, the typical way to express the second phrase would be "You didn't just call me with that name."